# How can i display the UIimagepickerController at the middle of the screen

Tags: iphone

I am developing one application.In that I am using the `UIImagePickerController`.That one will be opened total screen.But i need to open that picker at the middle of the `screen(50,50,220,380)`.So please tell mw how can i do this one.

Comment: did you even try any thing ? http://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=uiimagepickercontroller+change+frame&oq=uiimagepickercontroller+change+frame&gs_l=hp.3...69745.70274.5.70468.6.6.0.0.0.5.394.1467.2-3j2.5.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.hxE1C8A2WEc&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=3f7e71b5cbd4d390&biw=1600&bih=717

Comment: I tried all of them.But not working.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10164581/configuring-frame-size-of-uiimagepickercontroller.This one open the camera at the top of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a lovely miniature camera imagePicker floating in the middle of my screen using the following

```
 UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

imagePickerController.delegate = self;
//  imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage, nil];
imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
// imagePickerController.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

UIView *controllerView = imagePickerController.view;

controllerView.alpha = 0.0;
controllerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5);

[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addSubview:controllerView];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^{
                     controllerView.alpha = 1.0;
                 }
                 completion:nil
 ];
```

Comment: It was not given the imagepicker at the middle of the screen.

Comment: did u try adding imagePickerController.view to self.view??exactly what output are you getting

Comment: empty white screen and at the top of screen i got black color.